# how to convert markdown with sub-markdowns to ebook

Tags: epub, calibre, markdown

main.md contain sub-mds:

main.md

```
1. [1 - ](1.md)
1. [2 - ](2.md)
1. [3 - ](3.md)
1. [4 - ](4.md)
1. [5 - ](5.md)
1. [6 - ](6.md)
```

I use calibre command:

```
ebook-convert main.md main.epub
```

But only the content of main.md is wrote to epub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two things.

For me the link has to be written '( ./6.md )' with a space before and after the file specification.

Then I found the ebook-convert app wants html files for inputs.
It complains that the inputs are "binary"

Comment: Thanks, it seems that calibre doesn't support md format very well.

Comment: "It complains that the inputs are "binary"." This is probably caused by extended ascii characters in the source file which should be only 7 bit text. Find the high ascii characters and remove or replace them with low ascii characters. Or set the text source file as utf-8. How to do that depends on the editor you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I just use [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org) and specify all .md files on the command line. Here is an incomplete command line: `pandoc [some options] 1.md 2.md 3.md`.

Source files go last, after all other options, on the command line.